# Looking for advice with the following integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, dynamical-systems

I have the following integral to evaluate:
$$\frac{1}{f(t)} \int_0^t s^m f(s) \sin(ps) \mathrm{d}s \quad m,p \in \mathbb{R}$$

I'm unable to proceed with this integral as it is non-trivial. Even using a CAS doesn't help. Any suggestions with solving this in close-form somehow? Or is numerical integration my best bet?

Comment: What is $f$ here? Furthermore, the upper limit of the integrand is $t$ and the operator is also $dt$. Is this a misspelling?

Comment: I have edited the equation to hopefully be a bit clearer. $f(t)$ is some know function of time.

Comment: Now $m,n,o,p \in \mathbb{R}$. What is it? $n,o$ are unused variables. Is $t$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: oh. Forgot to take those out. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. Do we know anything about $f$? Is it differenciable on $[0,t]$? Is it finite in $[0,t]$? At least is it defined on the whole $[0,t]$?

Comment: So $f$ is differentiable and finite in [0,t] (and therefore defined in [0,t], right?) I did, however go about solving this problem by doing the following.

    I = Integrate[t^m * f[t] * Sin[p*t],t];

    x = I/f[t];

    Plot[x,{t,0,100}];


I think this is the right approach, but I just wanted to get clarification on the methodology.